# How can I animate an Image from left to right on scroll in my React project?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation, scroll

I want achieve an animation like apple website, I need to move an Image from left to right on scroll in my react project.

I need to move an Image from left to right on scroll in my react project. I have tried some packages of scroll animation but didn't work. there will be one section after some scroll and while reaching it the image should start moving from left to right and overlap on the right side image.

```
      <div className="w-[400vw] mb-10 lg:mb-[116px] px-6 flex" id="container" >
        <div className="sticky max-w-[1715px] left-0 w-full">
          <h2 className="max-w-[630px] mx-auto">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
          </h2>
          <div className="flex gap-[134px]">
            <div className="left">
              <img
                src="images/home/animation-left.png"
                width="471"
                height="790"
                alt="Mobile Screen"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="right">
              <img
                src="images/home/animation-right.png"
                width="1042"
                height="805"
                alt="In Hand Mobile"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```